# Remove almonds skin

Tags: food

Almonds are protein rich and I'm eating them daily, but it's really hard to remove it's skin. Is there any any easiest way to remove skin from almonds?

Comment: There are those that say cold soaking almonds (and most other seeds and nuts) for a day first to activate germination and deactivate various preservative enzymes is a very healthy thing.  The skin is probably rich in other things good for you, they are usually removed for cosmetic reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick solution is to put almonds in hot or boiling water for half hour to 45 minutes

Long solution is to put almonds in cold water overnight.

After this, you can easily remove the skin of the almonds

Comment: Boiling for *thirty* minutes? That's ridiculously long. A few minutes will suffice.